# Upgrading ipseccmd script (XP) to WIndows 7 using netsh

Tags: windows, scripting, netsh

Current script:

```
cd "%ProgramFiles%\Support Tools"
ipseccmd -w REG -p "IGA-B-Gone" -r "Block Outbound connections to IGA servers 72.3.184.144/28" -f 0=72.3.184.144/255.255.255.240::TCP -n BLOCK -x
ipseccmd -w REG -p "IGA-B-Gone" -r "Block Outbound connections to IGA servers 72.32.5.0/28" -f 0=72.32.5.0/255.255.255.240::TCP -n BLOCK -x
net stop policyagent
net start policyagent
```

I notice Windows 7 (and Vista) does not use ipseccmd but has netsh instead. I am unfamiliar with this tool how can I use it to block IP ranges?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule` command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(WS.10).aspx

You can set Inbound and Outbound rules that filter by IP there. You can make a custom rule once in the GUI and then use `show rule name ="blah"` to get a good idea what they set when you configure it.